# How to set encoding to utf-8 on a IIS web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, iis, encoding, utf-8

I have this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="ContentServer" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings />

    <system.web>
        <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="25" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="false" />
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="false" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

How do I set the encoding to utf-8 for files sent to client. Actually There can be other types of files sent to clients like js,css,images. But I have aspx pages, that I want to set `text/html; charset=utf-8"` content-type to. How can I add this to this web.config code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `responseEncoding` attribute of the [globalization element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
<globalization
    responseEncoding="utf-8"
/>
```

In context:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization 
           requestEncoding="utf-8"
           responseEncoding="utf-8"
        />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: where do I insert that into the web.config, and if I edit the web.config do I need to restart the IIS server?

Comment: Follow the link. The page has an example showing the element in context. When you edit web.config, IIS will automatically recycle the app pool; you won't need to perform an `iisreset` manually.